# Changing the default operator from OR to AND in Solr (Magento Enterprise)

Tags: magento, solr

I'm using Solr with Magento Enterprise. I'm trying to change the default search operator from `OR` to `AND` to make searches more specific by default.

The first thing I tried was to to change `defaultOperator` in `schema.xml` which did not have the desired effect (it started using `AND` between fields, not keywords).

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

I then read about [LocalParams](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LocalParams) and tried adding that to several `requestHandler` sections in `solrconfig.xml` (I'm just guessing where it's supposed to go, I can't find any helpful documentation).

```
<requestHandler name="magento_en" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="q.op">AND</str>
```

I also poked around in the code (`app/core/core/Enterprise/Search`), hard-coded `{!q.op=AND}` to the queries but still couldn't get it to work.

I imagine it's a simple configuration change, can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** To clarify, a search for "red jacket" (without quotes) should return results for "red AND jacket". I'm only interested in products that are actually red jackets, not red shoes and/or blue jackets. A manual search for "red AND jacket" returns the results that I'm after.

Currently a search performs these queries:

```
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={start=0&q=articles_title:red+jacket*+articles_summary:red+jacket*+articles_text:red+jacket*+cms_title:red+jacket*+cms_content:red+jacket*&json.nl=map&wt=json&fq=store_id:1+store_id:0&version=1.2&rows=4} hits=7 status=0 QTime=1 
09/01/2013 10:46:21 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={spellcheck=true&sort=attr_sort_score_en+desc&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&json.nl=map&wt=json&spellcheck.collate=true&version=1.2&rows=1&fl=id&start=0&q=(Red+jacket)&spellcheck.dictionary=magento_spell_en&q.op=AND&spellcheck.count=2&qt=magento_en&fq=(visibility:3+OR+visibility:4)+AND+store_id:1} hits=645 status=0 QTime=5 
09/01/2013 10:46:21 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={facet=on&sort=score+desc&json.nl=map&wt=json&version=1.2&rows=24&fl=id&start=0&facet.query=category_ids:8&facet.query=category_ids:46&facet.query=category_ids:88&facet.query=category_ids:126&facet.query=category_ids:168&facet.query=category_ids:180&facet.query=category_ids:207&facet.query=category_ids:224&facet.query=category_ids:242&facet.query=category_ids:276&q=(Red+jacket)&q.op=AND&facet.field=attr_nav_multi_colourway&qt=magento_en&fq=(visibility:3+OR+visibility:4)+AND+store_id:1} hits=645 status=0 QTime=5 
09/01/2013 10:46:22 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={facet=on&sort=attr_sort_score_en+desc&json.nl=map&wt=json&rows=100&version=1.2&start=0&facet.query=category_ids:8&facet.query=category_ids:46&facet.query=category_ids:88&facet.query=category_ids:126&facet.query=category_ids:168&facet.query=category_ids:180&facet.query=category_ids:207&facet.query=category_ids:224&facet.query=category_ids:242&facet.query=category_ids:276&q=(Red+jacket)&q.op=AND&facet.field=attr_nav_multi_colourway&qt=magento_en&fq=(visibility:3+OR+visibility:4)+AND+store_id:1} hits=645 status=0 QTime=6 
09/01/2013 10:46:22 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select params={facet=on&sort=attr_sort_score_en+desc&json.nl=map&wt=json&rows=100&version=1.2&start=0&facet.query=category_ids:8&facet.query=category_ids:46&facet.query=category_ids:88&facet.query=category_ids:126&facet.query=category_ids:168&facet.query=category_ids:180&facet.query=category_ids:207&facet.query=category_ids:224&facet.query=category_ids:242&facet.query=category_ids:276&q=(Red+jacket)&q.op=AND&facet.field=attr_nav_multi_colourway&qt=magento_en&fq=(visibility:3+OR+visibility:4)+AND+store_id:1} hits=645 status=0 QTime=3
```

Comment: can you post the query url that you are requesting?

Comment: @Max is this what you're after? http://pastebin.com/jqBABtwR

Comment: sort of. and what should the AND operator act on?
should it be (articles_title AND articles_summary) ?

Comment: It should be "red AND jacket" when you search for "red jacket". I updated my previous comment, it does several queries per search.

Comment: I do not usually click on any link...so, if possible, can you update your original post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I ended up overriding the `Enterprise_Search_Model_Adapter_HttpStream` model to inject `AND`s into the search query. I added the `prepareSearchConditions()` method from `Enterprise_Search_Model_Adapter_Solr_Abstract`:

```
<?php

class Foo_Search_Model_Adapter_HttpStream extends Enterprise_Search_Model_Adapter_HttpStream
{
    protected function prepareSearchConditions($query)
    {
        $query = str_replace(' ', ' AND ', str_replace(' AND ', ' ', $query));

        return parent::prepareSearchConditions($query);
    }
}
```

It doesn't play nice with other operators obviously but in my case it's *good enough*™ (at least for now). I'm still hoping to find a better solution though.

Answer (score 13):

Thanks to Macilias' link on the [dismax parser plugin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) I've found a way to accomplish this with the settings in the solrconfig.xml.  In this file there are requestHandler nodes for a bunch of different languages.  I modified the english one since our store is in english.  By default the xml looked like this:

```
<requestHandler name="magento_en" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="qf">fulltext_1_en^1.0 fulltext_2_en^2.0 fulltext_3_en^3.0 fulltext_4_en^4.0 fulltext_5_en^5.0</str>
        <str name="pf">fulltext_1_en^1.0 fulltext_2_en^2.0 fulltext_3_en^3.0 fulltext_4_en^4.0 fulltext_5_en^5.0</str>
        <int name="ps">1</int>
        <str name="mm">1</str>
        <str name="defType">dismax</str>
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

The important parameter here is "mm" which stands for [Minimum 'Should' Match](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29).  The dismax parser uses this instead of a default operator to determine how multiple search terms should be handled.  A value of 1 means only one term from the query must match (same behavior as OR).  A value of 100% mean all the terms must match (same behavior as AND).  More complex values can be used as well.  Follow the link above for more info.  After changing settings in the solrconfig.xml file you'll need to restart the Solr server before they take effect.

This video is also a good Magento Solr resource:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07uIJSXdqpU
They talk about Minimum Match around the 24 minute mark.

Comment: Great answer. The slides that are associated with the Youtube video can be found here: http://www.slideshare.net/grohl6669/start-your-search-engines-solr-and-magento/16

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using q.op which changed the operator to AND instead of OR. For example:

```
 ?q=text:small cars&q.op=AND
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (untested):

```
q={!q.op=AND df=articles_title}red jacket&fq=articles_summary:(red AND jacket)&fq=articles_text:(red AND jacket)
```

and the rest of the fields are used in a similar fashion with `fq` parameter.

The above will return all those records where all the mentioned fields contain term red and jacket. However, if you are required to return a record where atleast one field contains red AND jacket, then I suggest that you use a copyfield to map all those fields to a single field and then search against the copyfield type.

Comment: My question is not so much about the syntax but where to configure this so it applies to all searches. I'm guessing I need to add something to `solrconfig.xml`, one of the Magento specific config files or somewhere in the Magento Enterprise Search module code. Basically I only want to return products that are actually red jackets, not red shoes and/or blue jackets. Manually searching for "red AND jacket" returns the results that I'm after.

Comment: looks like the first '(' should be a '{' , but cant edit only one char: q={!q.op=AND...

Comment: @HugoZaragoza like this? That wasn't hard.

Answer (score 0):

```
My question is not so much about the syntax but where to configure this so it applies to all searches.
```

To answer your question, I am quite sure that we need to specify the default operator for solrQueryParser in schema.xml and not in solrconfig.xml. As you mentioned, it is given as,

```
< solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
```

The reason why you did not get expected results may be because of the following reason:

If your search URL is something like,

```
q=articles_summary:red+jacket
```

Then what happens is, **"red"** is searched against field **"articles_summary"** but **"jacket"** is searched against your **default search field** (say "text") which if I am right will be a **copy field** containing copy of all searchable fields. Hence you will get a match for "red" in "articles_summary" and "jacket" in "text".

To get what you expect, I suggest you use something like following URL after setting default operation to AND as you already did:

```
q=articles_summary:red+articles_summary:jacket
```

If you have multiple fields to search, you may have to do like this:

```
q=articles_summary:red+articles_summary:jacket+articles_title:red+articles_title:jacket
```

Comment: I'll try adding that to schema.xml. The thing is that I don't know where or how the query is constructed. I simply have a running instance of Solr and Magento handles the rest (a contractor who no longer works with us modified the schema a bit). When you say "use the following URL" I'm not sure where to apply the change.

Comment: I don't know if we can make configuration changes in Magento just like we do in plain Solr. But I think the following article may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168249/how-to-configure-magento-enterpise-to-use-solr-as-the-main-search-engine

Comment: Thanks. We've been through those steps, it's all set up and running. I have yet to find a good guide on tuning a Magento/Solr installation however.

Answer (score 0):

In solr you should use the dismax (or edismax) parser plugin. Here you can set the minimum should match to 100%. [you can find more information here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin)