# Can't set default query operator on Solr 3.6.*

Tags: solr

I'm having trouble setting the default operator on Solr 3.6.1 to OR using the edismax parser (q.op=OR)

I have the same collection in solr version 4.10.4 and 3.6.1

I search for: pascal fubar in 4.10.4 where the word fubar never occurs in any document. Looking at the debug information I see:

```
"parsedquery_toString": "+((name:maxtor) (name:fubar))",
```

this matches lots of docs (those with pascal in them).

I perform the same search on my 3.6.1 solr and see:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=maxtor+fubar&wt=json&indent=true&debugQuery=true&defType=edismax&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true&q.op=OR

+(((name:maxtor) (name:fubar))~2)
```

which basically says that fubar and pascal must occur within 2 positions. So this matches zero docs.

The query: pascal OR fubar works.

Has anyone got any pointers as to why the ~2 is getting added to the query? Just to note that I took a standard 4.10.4 solr config and merged the search handler from my 3.6.1 config so they are not 100% identical.

Comment: I've just tried this with a vanilla 3.6.1 with the standard example documents and it does the same. The default operator doesn't appear to work with the edismax parser.

Comment: Tried with 3.6.2, same issue. Works fine with default collection on 4.*. So I guess this is an edismax funny. I couldn't find any mention of it. Maybe q.op doesn't work with edismax on 3.6.* ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question as someone may have the same issue, it seems to be a feature (bug) of the 3.6+ and early 4.* dismax and edismax parsers. This answer gives some explaination

[Changing the default operator from OR to AND in Solr (Magento Enterprise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226424/changing-the-default-operator-from-or-to-and-in-solr-magento-enterprise)

and it seems related to this issue

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2649

In any event the 4.10.4 version solr I tried didn't behave in the same way.

The solution is to us a must match parameter of 1 for OR behavior

```
&mm=1
```

Hope this helps someone as it took me quite a long time to debug.